# Storing large amounts of data in the Asp.net session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm writing a C#/asp.net page, and currently lots of data (say 100 000 Datetime int pairs) that i pull out of a database on page load, however loading the same data every page load seems a little silly. I've considered storing this value in the session, but multiple browser tabs seems to be causing an issue.

Is there a better way to store these values, and is using the session appropriate if i need to support multiple browser tabs?

Comment: Is the data different for each user or is it the same data (DateTime Int pairs) for all users?

Comment: What do multiple tabs have to do with it?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `.Cache`, no?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your session eats up a lot of server memory. You could store your session in a database (which defeats the purpose since this is the reason why you want to store them in the session in the first place), but reading between the lines (why would each visitor need 100,000 unique datetime pairs?) I think you should really look into storing these values in the cache (if they're the same for all users).

The problem with storing 100k int pairs in the session is that it might work for 1 or 2, hell even a dozen users maybe. But when your website gets popular its not scalable at all. Your server won't be able to store 500,000 user sessions of 100k int pairs each. **You'll run out of memory pretty quickly**

Comment: Quickly doesn't even begin to describe how quickly the sever would run out of memory.

Comment: The data may be different depending on the type user, but i should be able to write some code to use the cache effectively. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If this data is unique per user, then the session might be a valid place to cache the data. Although, if you do this then you should be aware that something you add to the session stays there and will need removing. Also since you are storing a lot of data per user session, so you consume a lot of server memory. That's what Steve is getting at with his answer - you could easily find yourself running out of room with multiple users having massive session data

If the data does not vary per user, then the [cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The session could become unwieldy.  You may want to consider a master page to wrap your pages in.  You could then load the data once in the master, and keep it available across the pages, or place into a hidden object on the page (such as a literal) to be able to access.

Why do you need all of the pairs between pages?

Comment: Your solution to too much data is to put it on the view state and push it up and down to the client?

Comment: true -- could also put into a Javascript on the master, and let the client deal with it.  I like the solution below, cache it if it is the same for all users

Answer (score 0):

What about using caching instead of session variables: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx