# What to use instead of Session?

Tags: c#, session

As I read here, using Session is bad for storing large amounts of data.

I have a method in c# in a controller, which I call from javascript file (with ajax call). This method is called a lot of times, 500 or so. In this method I have a for loop which loops 10 times.

The first time I call it, I create new session and set it to null.
After that, all the times I call it, for every for loop, I add data to the session.

For small data, it works great. Actually it works even for big data. But the problem is - the bigger the number of call, the slower it gets. For 500 times it takes 5 hours.

I read here: [Storing large amounts of data in the Asp.net session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224973/storing-large-amounts-of-data-in-the-asp-net-session) that session isn't good for storing large amounts of data.

What should I use as an alternative?

I thought about saving it in db, but then every time I call the method, I will need to have two queries to db: one for getting the data, and two for resaving it.

What should I do to make it work faster?

Comment: Database would be the normal answer.  Maybe you could provide more details so we can understand exactly why a database would not work in this situation.  Can you show some code?

Comment: I agree with mbeckish. If you do not use database, you should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a single server? If so, you could store the data as a local file if it's too large to store in a database. That won't scale to multiple servers, though, unless they have a common file access somewhere. Otherwise, something like a database or distributed cache would be the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be very carefull with session. You can use for lookups data that are the same for all users, caching. See the above example of caching . http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/134784/MyCache-Distributed-caching-engine-for-an-ASP-NET